# About g++ -D in csh

Tags: c, shell, csh

I have a csh for C code as follow:

```
foreach i (COARSE_STATIC, COARSE_DYNAMIC, FINE_STATIC, FINE_DYNAMIC)
    foreach j (1 2 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60)
       g++ -o proj2 project2.cpp -O3 -lm -openmp -D=$i -DNUMT=$j
       ./proj2 >> OUT
     end
     echo '\n' >> OUT
end
```

I have some problem for the `-D=$i`, I know it is incorrect, I don't know how to modify it to express:

```
#define COARSE_STATIC
```

Does anyone could tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't put the `=` sign if you only need to define the macro.

```
g++ ... -D$i
```

Also you have comas `,` as a separator in your first for list, and not in the second. The second is correct and you should remove the comas in the first. (Otherwise you'll try to define the macro `CORESTATIC,`.)